# Query to find "active" ads in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm building an ad manager that has the following Schema:

```
<Campaign id: nil, target_id: nil, date_view_based: nil, start_date: nil, end_date: nil, max_views: nil, cur_views: nil, link_to: nil, alt_data: nil, title_attr: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, user_id: nil, image_file_name: nil, image_content_type: nil, image_file_size: nil, image_updated_at: nil, link_clicked: nil, name: nil>
```

What I need is a way to create a method that will run like this...

```
Campaigns.current?
```

And output an array of something like this

```
Campaign.where('date_view_based =? AND end_date >= ? AND start_date <= ?', "Date", Date.today.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'), Date.today.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')).concat(Campaign.where('date_view_based = ? AND max_views >= ?, "View", :cur_views))
```

However, the `Campaign.where('max_views >= ?, :cur_views)` doesn't work, so how can I compare these two attributes? Surely there must be  a better way to do this any suggestions would be appreciated.

Sorry I thought I had included the structure but I guess I didn't: `Campaign.new` returns:

```
#<Campaign id: nil, target_id: nil, date_view_based: nil, start_date: nil, end_date: nil, max_views: nil, cur_views: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, name: nil>
```

Comment: Since your where statement is using SQL rather than Ruby, make sure to use single = instead of double ==.

Comment: Thanks for catching my typo. Yes, it is just one = is there a way to query this in Ruby that would make it easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base

  # ...

  def self.current
    date_view_based_enum = %W(Date View)
    date = Date.today.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
    where("((start_date <= ? AND end_date >= ?) OR (max_views >= cur_views)) AND date_view_based IN (?)", date, date, date_view_based_enum)
  end
end
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for!